# Differentiating Cross Entropy Error in Bishops Machine Learning. Chapter on Neural Networks

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors, machine-learning

I have been trying to solve this problem from Bishop's Machine Learning chapter 5 for the past few hours, but I am confused as to how to show the below identity. I know I have to take a partial derivative wrt $a_k$ but I don't know how.

Show that the derivative of E(w)
$$E\left(w\right)=-\sum _{g=1}^G\:\left(t_g\cdot ln\left(y\left(a_g\right)\right)+\:\left(1-t_g\right)\cdot ln\left(1-y\left(a_g\right)\right)\right)
$$
wrt $a_g$ for output having logistic sigmoid activ. function where $y\left(a_g\right)=σ\left(a_g\right)$ satisfies

$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_k
g}=\left(y\left(a_g\right)-t_{g\:}\right),\:and\:given\:\frac{\partial σ\left(a_g\right)\:}{\partial \:a_g}=σ\left(a_g\right)\left(1-σ\left(a_g\right)\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

First differentiating the equation for $E$ with respect to $a_k$ (I am assuming $t_g$ is a constant):
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_k} 
= -\frac{\partial }{\partial a_k} \sum_g (t_g \cdot ln(y(a_g))
+(1-t_g)\cdot ln(1-y(a_g))) 
$$

$$
= -\sum_g \left[t_g \frac{y'(a_g)\delta_{gk}}{y(a_g)}
 + (1-t_g)\frac{-y'(a_g)\delta_{gk}}{1-y(a_g)}\right]
$$

where we have used the chain rule and $\frac{\partial a_g}{\partial a_k} = \delta_{gk}$ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta. Now evaluating the above sum becomes simple:

$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_k} = - t_k\frac{y'(a_k)}{y(a_k)} + (1-t_k)\frac{y'(a_k)}{1-y(a_k)}
$$

From here on I will drop the $k$ subscript to reduce clutter. Now we can plug in the property you gave for the sigmoid:

$$y'=y(1-y)$$

$$\implies \frac{\partial E}{\partial a_k} = -t \frac{y'}{y} + (1-t)\frac{y'}{1-y}$$
$$ = -t \frac{y(1-y)}{y}+(1-t)\frac{y(1-y)}{1-y}$$
$$ = -t(1-y) + (1-t)y$$

Finally, reintroducing the subscripts, we have

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_k} = y(a_k) - t_k$$

Comment: " Now evaluating the above sum becomes simple:" can you explain how you got this? @tabin

Comment: I would suggest reading a bit about the Kronecker delta, but here is the main idea: consider a sum of the form $\sum_i f_i \delta_{ij}$. Since $\delta_{ij}$ only non zero when $i=j$ (and it takes the value 1), the sum is only non-zero when $i=j$, so the sum evaluates to $f_j$. In practice, this means that whenever we have a Kronecker delta in a sum, we can get rid of the sum and just replace the summed over index by the other index in the Kronecker delta.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}$Drop
the subscripts and apply the `logistic` function elementwise on the vector argument $a$ to generate the vector $y,\;$ i.e.
$$\eqalign{
y &= \sigma(a) \quad&\implies\quad dy = (y-y\odot y)\odot da \\
Y &= \D(y) \quad&\implies\quad dy = (Y-Y^2)\,da  \\
}$$
where the Hadamard product $(\odot)$ can be replaced by matrix multiplication by a diagonal matrix. The same technique can be applied to the elementwise `log` functions
$$\eqalign{
w &= \log(y)\quad&\implies\quad dw = \frac{dy}{y} = Y^{-1}dy \\
x &= \log(\o-y)\quad&\implies\quad dx = \frac{dy}{y-\o} = (Y-I)^{-1}dy \\
}$$
It will be convenient to use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \\
}$$
since this allows the cost function to be written without an explicit summation symbol.
This purely matrix form is easy to differentiate.
$$\eqalign{
\E &=  (t-\o):x - t:w \\
d\E &= (t-\o):dx - t:dw \\
  &= (t-\o):(Y-I)^{-1}\c{dy} \;-\; t:Y^{-1}\c{dy} \\
  &= (\o-t):(I-Y)^{-1}\c{(Y-Y^2)\,da} \;-\; t:Y^{-1}\c{(Y-Y^2)\,da} \\
  &= (\o-t):Y\,da \;-\; t:(I-Y)\,da \\
  &= Y(\o-t):da \;+\; (Y-I)t:\,da \\
  &= (Y\o-It):da \\
  &= (y-t):da \\
\grad{\E}{a} &= (y-t) \\
}$$